# Why Javascript Button click event only works when one manual activity in the page?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, click, content-script

I'm having some strange problem, that following code only works when the Chrome debug window is opened, or only after clicking somewhere on the page.

Following code works fine on Chrome console.

```
var xPath = "//*[contains(@class,'ytp-play-button')]";
            var el = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;   
            if (el!=null)
            {
                //el.click(); 
                el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
            }
```

but, when executed in a content script, the el.click() method does not work, or had no any effect. But, if I click somewhere on the page before executing the above script, then the same code works fine.

I tried el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click')) instead of el.click(), and it also works after any other manual activity like clicking somewhere on the page.

But, when there were no manual activity before running the script, any of the above click methods had no effect, and no error.

The reason for same to work after opening the debug window, may be because I right click on the page and clicked the inspect element.

I tried el.focus() before click, but had no difference.

can anyone please point me in the right direction to identify the problem, or suggest an solution?

Comment: I have no idea how you can simulate a click on the Play button in a YouTube video. But why would you even want to? You can play a YT video directly: `document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream")[0].play();` And to pause it: `document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream")[0].pause();` There are many other functions and properties, and I'm sure they're documented somewhere.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller Thanks a lot. it seems the problem occurs only in Chrome browser, and there is no any issue with Edge browser.